# How to pass a handler to LocalBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(...)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, localbroadcastmanager

Android provides a global `registerReceiver()` with a signature that takes a `Handler`. When using `LocalBroadcastManager.registerReceiver()`, there is no method that takes a `Handler`. Why? How can I provide a `Handler` which will process the broadcast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When using LocalBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(), there is no method that takes a Handler. Why?

Why would there be? There's no method that takes a `HashMap` or a `Restaurant` either.

> How can I provide a Handler which will process the broadcast?

Your `BroadcastReceiver` instance can hold a `Handler` in a data member, on which it can forward the message.

Of course, in that case, there's little value in using `LocalBroadcastManager` in the first place. Just use the `Handler` (and perhaps a `Messenger`). Or, switch to an event bus that offers more threading flexibility, like greenrobot's EventBus, so you can get rid of the `Handler`.

Comment: I realize I can store an instance of a `Handler` inside the `BroadcastReceiver`. But the same holds true when registering a global `BroadcastReceiver`, yet Android provides a `registerReceiver` method that does take a `Handler`. This either indicates poor API design, or some lack of understanding on my part, thus my question. I do prefer to use some sort of messaging protocol as I think it yields cleaner code than just posting to a shared Handler from various services. Thanks for the pointer to greenrobot's EventBus, I'll take a look.

Comment: @zyamys: "yet Android provides a registerReceiver method that does take a Handler" -- I had never noticed it, nor have I seen it used. My guess is that it's not all that common, and when they whipped up `LocalBroadcastManager`, they skipped it in the interests of simplicity. `LocalBroadcastManager` is not meant to be a complete implementation of system-level broadcasts (just local), as it also does not offer ordered broadcasts, sticky broadcasts, etc. That being said, I do apologize for not knowing about the `Handler`-equipped `registerReceiver()`.

Comment: But the Handler could be used to make the receiver work on a HandlerThread no?